# webshpere application server not changing status to started

Tags: websphere, startup

I created new WAS 6.0 and 6.1 servers in RAD and they are starting fine and I'm getting the text "Server1 open for business" in WAS console. But they are not changing their status to "Started" in the servers tab.

Only when the status changes to "Started", I will be able to publish my applications.
I'm seriously stuck here.. Someone please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved!

Double click WAS server in RAD and in the properties window, change "Server Connection type and Admin port" from RMI to SOAP. Now the server should behave properly when started.

I'm not sure how it worked, but this solved the problem :D